# How to call a class definition from urls.py file

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I am using python 2.7 with django1.4.My class definition contains more than one method,So i need to call my method with url. How to call it..?My prog is like this

```
class upload(View):

    def imageUpload(self,request):
        a=request.GET['filename']
        -------
        ------
    def videoUpload(self,request):
        a=request.GET['filename']
        -------
        ------
    def fileUpload(self,request):
        a=request.GET['filename']
        -------
        ------
```

How to call these functions from urls.py..Thanks in advance

Comment: try this 'class upload(TemplateView):template_name = "about.html"` in your url ` (r'^upload/', upload.as_view()),`

Answer (score 0):

In order to register class method as a view with Django, you just import the class and use `as_view` classmethod:

From [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/class-based-views/) (for 1.4, but as of 1.6 it's still the same):

```
# some_app/views.py
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class AboutView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "about.html"

# urls.py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from some_app.views import AboutView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^about/', AboutView.as_view()),
)
```

You might want to read the docs about class-based views carefully before proceeding with your project. Class-based views are indeed a powerful tool, but they are different from simple functions in some ways, so there are some caveats.

Comment: Thanks for reply,Ya i am able to call class based as you mentioned above but i need to call a particular method in call a class.I am able to working with only one method either get or post.But i need to call my own method

Comment: Ok htink of it as if you are a url dispatcher. You only have a list of configured routes, request data and method. How would you call the appropriate method? IMHO, the simpliest way is to add a request parameter and a facade function to actually handle an incoming request and call the appropriate method based on request parameter value.

Other than that, looks like you are splitting video/file/image upload at the wrong place. Could this be a utility class other than a view?

Comment: Thanks for reply,that is not my actual requirement i mentioned as an example.I want more than one user defined function in class.So can't we have multiple methods in one class....?

Comment: Class-based views were designed to serve as request handlers. You can have as many user-defined functions as you want, but only those named after http verbs (`get`, `post`, etc.) can be used in urls. So you can't give arbitrary names to class-based view methods.

Answer (score 0):

This can help!

```
class upload(View):
    @api_view(['GET'])
    def imageUpload(request):
        a=request.GET['filename']
        -------
        ------
```

and in urls.py

```
path('imageUpload', upload.imageUpload)
```